# How to read a string from a text file and use in a Windows batch file to extract a substring

Tags: windows, batch-file, script

We have a text file that we need containing the following sample.  One constant string "D80" followed by another string:

```
D80KAAAAAA
D80KBBBBBB
D80KCCCCCC
```

We want to extract it using a Windows batch script file (not powershell) and FOR loop to get this output:

```
AAAAAA
BBBBBB
CCCCCC
```

So far we have gotten to this point.  For illustration, i have shown the different attempts at extracting the substring:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1 delims="    %%a   in (TPLIST.txt) do (
    echo %%a
    echo %%(a:~4,6)
    set substr1=%%(a:~4,6)%
    set substr2=%(a:~4,6)%
    set substr3=!(a:~4,6)!
    set substr4=%!(a:~4,6)!%
    echo %substr1%
    echo %substr2%
    echo %substr3%
    echo %substr4%
)
```

However, the extract of the substring fails:

```
C:\User>setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
C:\User>for /F "tokens=1 delims=" %a in (TPLIST.txt) do (
echo %a
 echo %(a:~4,6
)
C:\User>(
echo D80KAAAAAA
 echo %(a:~4,6
)
D80KAAAAAA
%(a:~4,6
C:\User>(
echo D80KBBBBBB
 echo %(a:~4,6
)
D80KBBBBBB
%(a:~4,6
C:\User>(
echo D80KCCCCCC
 echo %(a:~4,6
)
D80KCCCCCC
%(a:~4,6
C:\User>set substr1=%(a:~4,6)
C:\User>set substr2=~4,6)
C:\User>set substr3=!(a:~4,6)!
C:\User>set substr4=~4,6)!
C:\User>echo %(a:~4,6)
%(a:~4,6)
C:\User>echo ~4,6)
~4,6)
C:\User>echo ~4,6)
~4,6)
C:\User>echo ~4,6)
~4,6)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In Pure batch file you can do something like that :

```
@echo off
Set "InputFile=TPLIST.txt"
Set "OutPutFile=%~dp0Out-Extract.txt"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
> "%OutPutFile%" (
    @for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%InputFile%"') do (
    set "_MyString=%%a"
    echo !_MyString:~4!
    )
)
endlocal
If Exist "%OutPutFile%" Start "" "%OutPutFile%"
```

---

In Powershell if another member wants to test using RegEx:

```
cls
$MyString = @'
D80KAAAAAA
D80KBBBBBB
D80KCCCCCC
D80KDDDDDD
D80KEEEEEE
D80KFFFFFF
D80KXXXXXX
D80KYYYYYY
D80KZZZZZZ
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$pattern = '(?![D80K]).+'
$MyString | %{ [regex]::matches($_,$pattern) } | %{ $_.Groups[0].Value }
```

---

You will get as output for both solutions batch or powershell like that :

> ```
> AAAAAA
> BBBBBB
> CCCCCC
> DDDDDD
> EEEEEE
> FFFFFF
> XXXXXX
> YYYYYY
> ZZZZZZ
> ```

Comment: Thank you--this does far more than the original request!  Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

#### Howdo I extract a substring?

Your script is horribly broken so I rewrote it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%a in (test.txt) do (
  set _s1=%%a
  set _s2=%%b
  set _s3=%%c
  echo !_s1:~4!
  echo !_s2:~4!
  echo !_s3:~4!
  )
endlocal
```

Example usage:

```
F:\test>type test.txt
D80KAAAAAA D80KBBBBBB D80KCCCCCC

F:\test>test
AAAAAA
BBBBBB
CCCCCC
F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [For /f - Loop through text - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [variable substring - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Comment: Thank you so much @DavidPostill for your kind answer.  The insights are great!  

i am not sure if my formatting got messed up but my input file is a single vertical column with three lines:
F:\test>type test.txt
D80KAAAAAA 
D80KBBBBBB 
D80KCCCCCC

whereas i think you interpreted it as a single line with three columns:
F:\test>type test.txt
D80KAAAAAA D80KBBBBBB D80KCCCCCC

(I think you are right about things being "horribly broken" but it was probably my formatting, my apologies.  I am new to this site)

Thank you again!  i will try this further for one column.